# How to prevent silently discarding attributes in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I'm very new to both PHP and to the barely-documented legacy codebase I'm debugging.  One of the attributes on one of my models is being set to NULL on DB save, and I'm not clear why.  This Q is mainly about my attempts to seal off one of the possibilities.

(It might be a type-conversion error - the model treats the field as an integer but the DB thinks it is a string, or that some code sets the field and other code doesn't, or that there are large sections of unreachable code and probably a few other possibilities too. Am tracing code, but it's a few dozen files of undocumented proprietary code, so please bear with me.  It's tough to make a minimal reproducible example under the circumstances.)

I came across [this article on configuring Eloquent strictness](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#configuring-eloquent-strictness), and "silently discarding" this attribute sounded a lot like "set it to null without logging an exception", so I figured I'd try it.  (The field of concern is listed in its particular model's `protected $fillable` attribute, so I might also be barking up the wrong tree...) As per the article, my (pre-existing, presumably working) `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` now contains this import:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
```

and it also contains the following function definition:

```
/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    $this->trackDatabaseEvents();
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
    Model::preventSilentlyDiscardingAttributes(! $this->app->isProduction());
}
```

where I've only added the third line, and it's copied directly from the above how-to, and also appears [in a couple](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/44094) other [contexts](https://planetscale.com/blog/laravels-safety-mechanisms#:%7E:text=Laravel%20now%20provides%20a%20way%20to%20make%20that%20silent%20error%20explicit%3A)... but when I try to compile the app, I get

```
#23 10.45 Generating optimized autoload files
#23 12.89 > Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
#23 12.91 > @php artisan package:discover --ansi
#23 13.08 [2023-01-24 14:27:57] production.ERROR: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Name or service not known (SQL: select * from "applications" limit 1)  
#23 13.11 [2023-01-24 14:27:57] production.ERROR: [0] "Cannot instantiate abstract class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model" on line 59 of file /app/app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php  
#23 13.11 
#23 13.11    Error 
#23 13.11 
#23 13.11   Cannot instantiate abstract class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
#23 13.11 
#23 13.11   at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:2144
#23 13.12     2140▕      * @return mixed
#23 13.12     2141▕      */
#23 13.12     2142▕     public static function __callStatic($method, $parameters)
#23 13.12     2143▕     {
#23 13.12   ➜ 2144▕         return (new static)->$method(...$parameters);
#23 13.12     2145▕     }
#23 13.12     2146▕ 
#23 13.12     2147▕     /**
#23 13.12     2148▕      * Convert the model to its string representation.
#23 13.12 
#23 13.12   1   app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php:59
#23 13.12       Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::__callStatic()
#23 13.12 
#23 13.12       +7 vendor frames 
#23 13.12   9   [internal]:0
#23 13.12       Illuminate\Foundation\Application::Illuminate\Foundation\{closure}()
#23 13.14 Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

I *am* using Postgres, and I can successfully compile the app if I copy out that one additional command in boot: `Model::preventSilentlyDiscardingAttributes(! $this->app->isProduction());`.  Compilation in both cases is via Docker, and the crashing is at `RUN composer install`.  Here's a trimmed version of the Dockerfile so folks can check version numbers, etc:

```
FROM ubuntu:focal as build

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y software-properties-common \
    && add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php \
    && apt-get install -y php8.1-fpm php8.1-cli php8.1-curl \
       php8.1-mbstring php8.1-xml php8.1-pgsql php8.1-intl php8.1-zip php8.1-gd \
       php8.1-gmagick php8.1-dev php-pear \
       libpq-dev libevent-dev libssl-dev netcat unzip \
    && curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer \
    && printf "\n" | pecl install event

WORKDIR /app

< a bunch of COPY commands; trimmed for space >

RUN composer install
    # --ignore-platform-reqs \
    # --no-interaction \
    # --no-plugins \
    # --no-scripts \
    # --prefer-dist
```

I don't know why those options are commented out, but might be able to find out.  I included them here in case everyone assumes that I had one of them or some other option present.  The options are the same - and commented out - both with and without the crash. The only change is the presence / absence of the `Model::preventSilentlyDiscardingAttributes` line in `AppServiceProvider.php`

Also, one of the comments asked about the `docker-compose.yml`.  There *is* such a file, but I need to build the image before I can "compose" multiple images together. The other images referenced in the docker-compose are not running either when I have this line enabled or disabled.

Another of the comments got me looking into [Composer Scripts](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#what-is-a-script-) and after skimming that page, I looked in my `composer.json`.  That contains a scripts section:

```
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
```

I don't know if that's causing the problem, but "`@php artisan package:discover --ansi`" does appear at the end of the previously-quoted traceback.

To provide a bit more detail about the field "`data_source`" whose odd behavior started me down this path:  The comment block just before the model class definition includes the line `* @property mixed $data_source`. Values assigned to the field in code always use constants defined on the class, and those constants are always integers.  It is intended to act as a short enum type, there are three values (other than null): 1, 2, and 3. There is also a class-constant array which maps two of those three integers to strings, but use of that array during read & save is inconsistent, and grep for the map's name doesn't reveal anything that looks to me like automatic type-casting. If I view records from the DB in pgAdmin, it shows the column data type as "character varying (10)".  All records in the DB have NULL values in that column. Some of the code that saves/updates records specifically set the column; some does not.  So I'm adding log messages to try to figure out which pieces of code are actually involved.

The PHP version is 8.1.16 and the ORM is Laravel Framework 8.83.27

Thank you for your attention and your help.

Comment: So, there is a lot going on, I am very confused... first of all, your `RUN composer install` is correct without `--ignore-platform-reqs`, you should never use that flag as if there are incompatibilities, it will not tell you. So then, when you get the address error, can you show us how does your docker compose file look like? The error says it cannot reach that address, not that it is ignoring something and setting it as `null`. Then, which column exactly is having this weird issue? Share migration, and the whole model to check out if there are casts or anything similar, please

Comment: Is this a SQL problem, or a Composer problem?

Comment: @matiaslauriti Added some details. My understanding is that `docker build` has to succeed before `docker compose` does anything.  I thought `docker compose` only linked together images after they had been built? The failure happens during _build_...  Or are you saying that `Model::preventSilentlyDiscardingAttributes` requires a running DB instance before `composer install` will run?  The `database/migrations/` directory is 93 files long.  Presumably you don't want me to share all of them...  The particular model file with the issue is over 500 lines long.  I'll add some info on the odd field.

Comment: I see I've got a couple votes to close... would this be better split into separate questions?  One for the field and one for the `Model::preventSilentlydiscardingAttributes`?  Are there good resources I can review to try to better understand the problem and narrow the scope of my question?

Comment: Are you saying you are running database stuff when building an image? That is not good at all, you must just build the image (php in this case I assume), so then docker compose run the container, we need to know a little bit more how you are using this image. I totally discourage doing anything else appart from building an image when building an image, like running composer install, or npm install, or anything similar, because if it fails (like your case), you have no image at all

Comment: @matiaslauriti As far as I know, I am *not* running DB stuff while building the image. Agree that I shouldn't.  I was responding to your comment about docker compose and the error message looking like it was trying to contact the Postgres DB. The only place which seems to rely on a DB call is the `Model::preventSilentlyDiscardingAttributes()` call - which I thought was a configuration command, _not_ a DB hit.  Are you saying that Laravel requires a DB contact in order to do that portion of configuration?

Comment: @NicoHaase I assume it's a composer problem, in that I'm not running any SQL during build.  But I don't now how Laravel implements `Model::preventSilentlyDiscardingAttributes()` - if PHP/Artisan's `composer install` requires a live DB connection and custom SQL just to modify Laravel's default safety config I guess that would explain the observations...

Comment: `composer install`  does not require a database connection, the scripts you configured might require that

Comment: @NicoHaase Thank you. Where would I find such scripts?  What am I looking for? Raw SQL? particular PHP file paths? Files referenced by name in `/app/config/app.php` ?  There aren't any RUN commands in the Dockerfile other than the two I listed explicitly in the Question.

Comment: @NicoHaase found an article on composer scripts and added a bit to the question, though I'm not sure how relevant those are - or if there are additional scripts I should find somewhere.

Comment: Which Laravel version are you using? `preventSilentlyDiscardingAttributes` has only been added in 9.28

Comment: PHP is 8.1.16.  Thanks @Thorstenvv

Comment: No, I mean the *Laravel* version, not PHP.

Comment: Laravel Framework 8.83.27

Comment: Please add **all** clarification to your question by editing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is due to `preventSilentlyDiscardingAttributes` not being present in the version of the Laravel framework you are using. It was added in 9.28.0 (but not fully working as expected, later got fixed).

If upgrading to a newer version of the framework is not an option, you may consider a workround like the one I used in my project by backporting the logic into your model classes. Here is what I did.

I created a BaseModel that contains the corresponding logic that was implemented in `preventSilentDiscardingAttributes` and applies it in the development environment:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\MassAssignmentException;

class BaseModel extends Model {
    public function fill( array $attributes ) {

    if ( env( 'APP_ENV' ) !== 'production' ) {
        $fillable = $this->fillableFromArray( $attributes );

        foreach ( $fillable as $key => $value ) {
            // The developers may choose to place some attributes in the "fillable" array
            // which means only those attributes may be set through mass assignment to
            // the model, and all others will just get ignored for security reasons.
            if ( ! $this->isFillable( $key ) ) {
                throw new MassAssignmentException( sprintf(
                    'Add [%s] to fillable property to allow mass assignment on [%s].',
                    $key, get_class( $this )
                ) );
            }
        }
        if ( count( $attributes ) !== count( $fillable ) ) {
            $keys = array_diff( array_keys( $attributes ), array_keys( $fillable ) );

            throw new MassAssignmentException( sprintf(
                'Add fillable property [%s] to allow mass assignment on [%s].',
                implode( ', ', $keys ),
                get_class( $this )
            ) );
        }
    }
        parent::fill( $attributes );

        return $this;
    }
}
```

I then extend this `BaseModel` for all my model classes.